# Getting unhandled exception running/installing nuget

Tags: apt, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to install nuget on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.  I'm getting errors and I don't know how to repair things from this state.

nuget doesn't launch, it gives the following Unhandled Exception error about `System.Console`.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Console' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ConsoleDriver' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00000] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00000] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.Exists (System.String path) [0x0001e] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.TermInfoDriver.SearchTerminfo (System.String term) [0x00044] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.TermInfoDriver..ctor (System.String term) [0x0004b] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.ConsoleDriver.CreateTermInfoDriver (System.String term) [0x00000] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.ConsoleDriver..cctor () [0x0004d] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Console.SetupStreams (System.Text.Encoding inputEncoding, System.Text.Encoding outputEncoding) [0x00007] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.Console..cctor () [0x0007d] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at NuGet.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00005] in <dc8a236afba24badbb185682f8956bec>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Console' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ConsoleDriver' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00000] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.IO.FileSystem.DirectoryExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00000] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.Exists (System.String path) [0x0001e] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.TermInfoDriver.SearchTerminfo (System.String term) [0x00044] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.TermInfoDriver..ctor (System.String term) [0x0004b] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.ConsoleDriver.CreateTermInfoDriver (System.String term) [0x00000] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.ConsoleDriver..cctor () [0x0004d] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Console.SetupStreams (System.Text.Encoding inputEncoding, System.Text.Encoding outputEncoding) [0x00007] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
  at System.Console..cctor () [0x0007d] in <81342d83acda4c5590ec19c7afdf26b9>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at NuGet.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00005] in <dc8a236afba24badbb185682f8956bec>:0
```

To try to fix it, I did this:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install -y >log.txt 2>&1
```

And here is the log.txt.  Sorry, it's brutally long, but I'm not sure what parts of it are relevant.

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb busybox-static cryptsetup-bin dpkg-repack
  gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 grub-common kde-window-manager kinit
  kio kpackagetool5 kwayland-data kwin-common kwin-data kwin-x11
  libdebian-installer4 libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private5v5
  libkf5activities5 libkf5attica5 libkf5completion-data libkf5completion5
  libkf5declarative-data libkf5declarative5 libkf5doctools5
  libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5
  libkf5idletime5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kcmutils-data
  libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kiowidgets5
  libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5package-data
  libkf5package5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5solid5
  libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5
  libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5waylandclient5
  libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data libkf5xmlgui5
  libkscreenlocker5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1 libkwineffects11
  libkwinglutils11 libkwinxrenderutils11
  libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil
  libnunit-cil-dev libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil libnunit-core2.6.3-cil
  libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil libnunit-util2.6.3-cil
  libqgsttools-p1 libqt5designer5 libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5
  libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5
  libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5test5 libqt5webchannel5
  libqt5webkit5 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-damage0 os-prober
  python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-icu python3-pam python3-pyqt5
  python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-sip
  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-qtmultimedia
  qml-module-qtquick2 rdate
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-mono
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates-mono
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 278 not upgraded.
157 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/31.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B disk space will be freed.
Setting up mono-gac (6.0.0.313-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libnewtonsoft-json5.0-cil into Mono

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in :0 
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in :0 
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in :0 
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in :0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in :0 
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in :0 
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in :0 
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in :0 
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/Newtonsoft.Json-5.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll failed
E: Installation of libnewtonsoft-json5.0-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil into Mono
```

*...lots of similar exceptions removed...*

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in :0 
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in :0 
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in :0 
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in :0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: System.Native
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.Stat(byte&,Interop/Sys/FileStatus&)
  at Interop+Sys.Stat (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] path, Interop+Sys+FileStatus& output) [0x00028] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath, System.Int32 fileType, Interop+ErrorInfo& errorInfo) [0x00007] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileSystem.FileExists (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] fullPath) [0x00006] in :0 
  at System.IO.File.Exists (System.String path) [0x00043] in :0 
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.LoadConfig (System.Boolean quiet) [0x00028] in :0 
  at Mono.Tools.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00351] in :0 
E: installing Assembly /usr/share/cli-common/policies.d/libnewtonsoft-json5.0-cil/policy.5.0.Newtonsoft.Json.dll failed
E: Installation of policy.5.0.Newtonsoft.Json with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
dpkg: error processing package mono-gac (--configure):
 installed mono-gac package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 29
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-runtime-common:
 mono-runtime-common depends on mono-gac (= 6.0.0.313-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1); however:
  Package mono-gac is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mono-runtime-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mono-gac
 mono-runtime-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this as well on a script that previously worked fine. This is due to a Mono upgrade from 5.18.0.x to 6.0.0 which was recently released (July 14th, 2019).

I was able to reproduce the error with both NuGet 4.7.0.5148 (on OSX) and 5.1.0.6013 (on Ubuntu 18.04).

After managing to downgrade Mono to 5.18.1 on my Mac the script worked again. Am currently still stuck on Ubuntu 18.04 though as the downgraded Mono is now running into libc exceptions.